# VB.NET Scope of resource created using "New" statement in argument to subroutine

Tags: vb.net, scope, new-operator, dispose, using

I was wondering, in VB.NET is:

```
Using tBrush = New SolidBrush(UseColor)      
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(tBrush, someRect)    
End Using
```

equivalent to:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(UseColor), someRect)
```

?

i.e. in the second case will the SolidBrush be released right after the FillRectangle finishes?

Answer (score 3):

It is true `Using` blocks create their own scope... but so do method calls, as in the second example. .Net is smart enough to know the brush is not reachable anywhere else. Therefore, considered only in terms of scope, the two options are close enough to not have any meaningful difference.

But scope isn't the big issue here. We also need to talk about disposal.

In the first example, the brush *will* be disposed as soon as the code block is finished. In the second example the brush merely becomes *eligible* to be disposed, but the exact time at which that disposal happens is still undetermined.

*Usually* the dispose will happen fairly quickly, even in the second case, and *usually* there is enough of this resource it doesn't matter much if it's delayed a little. However, sometimes it can take a while, and with some resource types, or in some environments where there is more contention, any potential delay can be a *big* problem. And since you don't always control the environment where the code runs, it's a good idea stick with a `Using` block whenever you have a type that implements `IDisposable`.

I also need to point out disposal has **nothing** to do with memory. Again, both samples share a similar scope, and so both will have their memory reclaimed by the garbage collector in similar ways. Rather, the resource governed by the disposal in this sample is the [GDI handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects) used by the brush. Without an explicit disposal, that GDI Handle would only be released when the garbage collector eventually gets around to calling the object's finalizer. That could be a while on a system with low memory pressure, hence the need for a different mechanism (`IDisposable` + `Using`) to reclaim it.

Comment: Would this dispose immediately as in the first example:
`Dim tBrush = New SolidBrush(UseColor)
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(tBrush, someRect)
tBrush.Dispose()`

Comment: @twhuttar Only if the code runs cleanly. An exception could cause it to miss the Dispose call. `Using` guarantees disposal even if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer, yes they are equivalent. And yes, the second brush will be released and at some point the garbage collector will get it.

The first one is interesting, though, if you want to use the same brush for several rectangles, instead of instantiating a bunch of brush. You could get a similar result by initiating your brush as a named variable and using it until it's out of scope, if it was preferable to your needs.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Using / End Using would release the resource immediately and not wait for the GC.  Is that not the case?

Comment: The GC release the resources which are not referenced anymore or that fell out of scope, but it doesn't do it right away. There's a method to it, which I'm not familiar with except for the fact that the GC will "come more often" when you have less memory available. In some cases, you may have strange behaviors because of that, for example if an unreferenced object which has yet to be collected receive an event and try to act on it.